# What calling convention is this in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc

I have a function in a program called with this assembly:

```
push xxx
push xxx
call xxx
add esp, xxx
```

From what I know this function has the *cdecl* calling convention.
In GCC I use `__attribute__((cdecl))` to make another function act the same as the above function.

But when I debugged it this assembly was shown:

```
push xxx
push xxx
call xxx
```

there is no `add esp, xxx`!

What calling convention should I use in order to produce the same assembly?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is here or how this would be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt this has anything to do with calling conventions, and is more likely to do with a compiler optimization like "defer-pop" (where the compiler will wait to pop the stack until later on)